# Создать один элемент при нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Если добавить две кнопки, то при нажатии на первую созданную кнопку, добавляется два input, нажал на вторую - добавляется один input.
Как уйти от этих дублей

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let add_button = document.querySelector('.add_button');
let i = 0;

add_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  i++;
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.className = 'button';
  button.innerHTML = 'Добавить input ' + i;
  container.append(button);
  addInput();
});

function addInput() {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
  buttons.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
      let input = document.createElement('input');
      container.append(input);
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="add_button">Добавить кнопку</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Что работает не так? Не совсем ясен ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант заменить `addEventListener('click', ...)` на `onclick`

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let add_button = document.querySelector('.add_button');
let i = 0;

add_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  i++;
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.className = 'button';
  button.innerHTML = 'Добавить input ' + i;
  container.append(button);
  addInput();
});

function addInput() {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
  buttons.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.onclick = function() {
      let input = document.createElement('input');
      container.append(input);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="add_button">Добавить кнопку</button>
</div>
```

#### Объяснение

`addEventListener` - добавляет новое событие, а если мы будет вместо него использовать `onclick`, то тогда будет перезаписывать текущее, тоесть вместо создания, будет перезапись события.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Эти дубли были из-за связки цикла и addEventListener ?

Comment: @Максим да, там заново добавлялось событие, у меня же оно заменялось. То есть для примера в `addEventListener` один раз добавилось событие, и после повторного вызова `addInput` оно снова добавляется. А вот в `onclick`, событие хранится в пропорции и вместо добавления нового, мы перезаписываем текущее.

Comment: понял, спасибо за разъяснения